public int State { get; set; } = -0;
I have the following code, who can explain what is the meaning of "= -0" at the end of the "state" property definition?
public class Subject
{
    public int State { get; set; } = -0;
}


It's just the initial value of the property. It's very odd to write -0 for an integer, particularly as zero would be the default value anyway, but it's still valid.
That's basically equivalent to:
public class Subject
{
    public int State { get; set; }

    public Subject()
    {
        State = -0;
    }
}

... it's also semantically just equivalent to:
public class Subject
{
    public int State { get; set; }
}

... which is how I'd normally write it.
